# How to pass props parameter with axios in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, axios

I am passing a property in another component via props:

```
props: ['product']
```

This Product has some properties like: `id`, `name` etc.

Now, I want to get the category of this product with id via axios.

Is it possible? How?
My try:

```
mounted () {
   axios
   .get('/categoryofaproduct/', {
       params: {
          id: this.product.id
       }
   })
   .then(response => {
       console.log(response)
  })
}
```

Comment: What doesn't work? Assuming you are using Express.js, you should be able to get the `id` with `request.query.id` in your server file

Answer (score 1):

I think `Props` properties will not be accessable directly like this.

```
data() {
  return {
     id: null,
     categoryName: null
  }
}
```

In mounted you can copy the id like this and then it will work.

```
mounted () {
  this.id = this.product.id
  axios.get('/categoryofaproduct/'+this.id)
    .then(response => {
      this.categoryName = response.data
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to use back ticks to make it a string literal and interpolation to insert the values in. This just makes it more readable when you have multiple parameters in a URL

```
mounted () {
   axios
   .get(`/categoryofaproduct/${this.product.id}`
                 
)
   .then(response => {
       console.log(response)
  })
}
```

Then accept that parameter on your route

```
 {
      // create route with id as a parameter
      path: "/categoryofaproduct/:id",
      name: "category-of-a-product",
      component: () => import("./views/categoryofaproduct.vue"),
    },
```

To get access to that param create a computed field that returns it

```
 computed: {
    paramsId() {
      return this.$route.params.id
    },
}
```